# Is it possible to use functions in Haskell parameters?

Tags: function, haskell, parameters

I have seen a few examples of Haskell code that use functions in parameters, but I can never get it to work for me.

example:

```
    -- Compute the nth number of the Fibonacci Sequence
    fib 0 = 1
    fib 1 = 1
    fib (n + 2) = fib (n + 1) + fib n
```

When I try this, it I get this error:

```
    Parse error in pattern: n + 2
```

Is this just a bad example? Or do I have to do something special to make this work?

Comment: Maybe this is of interest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010

Comment: These so-called (n + k) patterns were banned from Haskell some time ago. Replace third line with: `fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)`.

Comment: NB There is another way you can see function calls on the left hand side of an equation: [ViewPatterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns).  I'm rather surprised they aren't more common.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have seen is a special type of pattern matching called "n+k pattern", which was removed from Haskell 2010. See [What are "n+k patterns" and why are they banned from Haskell 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010) and http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RemoveNPlusK

Answer (score 3):

As Thomas mentioned, you can use View Patterns to accomplish this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib ((subtract 2) -> n) = fib (n + 1) + fib n
```

Due to the ambiguity of `-` in this case, you'll need to use the `subtract` function instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to help out, being a total newbie in Haskell.

I believe that the problem is that you can't match (n + 2).
From a logical viewpoint, any argument "n" will never match "n+2", so your third rule would never be selected for evaluation.

You can either rewrite it, like Michael said, to:

```
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

or define the whole fibonnaci in a function using guards, something like:

```
fibonacci :: Integer -> Integer
fibonacci n
| n == 0 = 0
| (n == 1 || n == 2) = 1
| otherwise = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Comment: I think you mean *guards*, not pattern matching in your last example.

Comment: Indeed I do, like a said... a newb, and I ended up abusing the language. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern matcher is limited to **constructor functions**. So while you can match the arguments of functions like `(:)` (the list constrcutor) or `Left` and `Right` (constructors of `Either`), you can't match arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `fib (n+2) = ...` notation doesn't work and is a syntax error. You can use "regular expression" style matching for paramters, like lists or tuples:

```
foo (x:xs) = ...
```

where x is the head of the list and xs the remainder of the list or

```
foo (x:[]) =
```

which is matched if the list only has one element left and that is stored in x. Even complex matches like

```
foo ((n,(x:xs)):rg) = ...
```

are possible. Function definitions in haskell is a complex theme and there are a lot of different styles which can be used.

Another possibility is the use of a "switch-case" scheme:

```
foo f x | (f x) = [x]
foo _ _ = []
```

In this case, the element "x" is wrapped in a list if the condition `(f x)` is true. In the other cases, the f and x parameters aren't interesting and an empty list is returned.

To fix your problem, I don't think any of these are applicable, but why don't throw in a catch-remaining-parameter-values function definition, like:

```
fib n = (fib (n - 1)) + (fib (n - 2))
```

Hope this helps,

Oliver

Answer (score 1):

Since `(+)` is a function, you can't pattern match against it. To do what you wanted, you'd need to modify the third line to read: `fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)`.