# Recursive function and stopping condition in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am implementing a recursive function and I want the stopping condition be **(2*scope)** which is parameter to function

```
sortByManhattanDistance agent (2*scope) scope xs sortedNearFoodList = sortedNearFoodList

sortByManhattanDistance agent n scope xs sortedNearFoodList = sortByManhattanDistance agent (n+1) scope xs (sorted ++ sortedNearFoodList) 
where sorted=compareManhattanDistance xs agent n
```

and hugs complain that: `Syntax error in declaration (unexpected symbol "*")`
Does it mean that I cannot use some function on parameters?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use `(2*scope)` as a input argument value. That is not a valid syntax

Comment: yeah i forgot it. thanks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot use functions or operators on the left hand side of an equation like that.

The proper way to do what you want is to use [guards](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Truth_values#Guards):

```
sortByManhattanDistance agent n scope xs sortedNearFoodList
    | n == 2 * scope = sortedNearFoodList
    | otherwise      = sortByManhattanDistance agent (n+1) scope xs
                                            (sorted ++ sortedNearFoodList) 
  where sorted = compareManhattanDistance xs agent n
```

Comment: i forgot about this! your advice was very useful