# Parse error in pattern: n + 1

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, parse-error

Trying to load a function within a file:

```
Prelude> :load "prova.hs"

prova.hs:37:9: Parse error in pattern: n + 1
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prova.hs, interpreted )
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

This should create a list which contains n times the repeated value x:

```
ripeti :: Int -> a -> [a]
ripeti 0 x = []
ripeti (n+1) x = x:(ripeti n x)
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: So-called *n+k patterns* are no longer supported in Haskell. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010

Comment: You are right, I was following Erik Meijer's lessons which says this is possible

Comment: @ChrisTaylor You should but this an answer so this question can be marked as closed and we can give you internet points.

Comment: You can use :set -XHaskell98 to make this work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code uses something called "n + k patterns" which are not supported in Haskell 2010 (they were supported in Haskell 98).

You can read a bit more about it at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010).

To get your code to work, you can write

```
ripeti :: Int -> a -> [a]
ripeti 0 x = []
ripeti n x = x : ripeti (n-1) x
```

Note that this will not terminate if you supply a negative value for `n`, so I would rather define

```
ripeti :: Int -> a -> [a]
ripeti n x | n <= 0    = []
           | otherwise = x : ripeti (n-1) x
```