# Mutual recursion in odd/even functions in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, ghci

In chapter 6 of **"Programming in Haskell"** by Graham Hutton there is a section called "6.5 Mutual recursion", that contains the following example:

```
even :: Int -> Bool
even 0       = True
even (n + 1) = odd n

odd :: Int -> Bool
odd 0       = False
odd (n + 1) = even n
```

I wanted to try it out. I put the code in Hof.hs file, ran **ghci**(version 7.8.3), typed

```
:l Hof.hs
```

and got the following error message

```
Hof.hs:3:7: Parse error in pattern: n + 1
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why am I getting this message? Is the code syntactically out of date or something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[n + k patterns have been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010) from Haskell and are no longer available. Write it like this instead:

```
even :: Int -> Bool
even 0 = True
even n = odd (n - 1)

odd :: Int -> Bool
odd 0 = False
odd n = even (n - 1)
```

Note that this function fails horribly for negative inputs, so you probably want to augment it with `abs`.

Comment: I think this is really looking at natural numbers and using `Int` for convenience. Bringing in `abs` probably doesn't make sense. Better would be to use Peano naturals: `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat`, then `even Zero = True; even (Succ n) = odd n; odd Zero = False; odd (Succ n) = even n`.

Comment: @dfeuer Why doesn't that make sense though? A negative integer is even if it is divisible by 2 and odd otherwise. Although, the implementation you give, with its pattern matching, does fit the original from the question more closely.

Comment: @DavidYoung, I take that back. If you're using a representation of integers as natural numbers with a sign, then absolute value is a perfectly reasonable way to do that. But *none* of this makes sense for `Int`, which is 2's complement binary!

Answer (score 0):

Our own language is quite powerful. I was having difficulty with limits when teaching myself calculus until I read one sentence in one paragraph of Newton. It was, of course, in English.

First off, you are correct about the indexing not being used or needed.

Secondly, the code does not know the difference between even or odd and you are again right to question it.

Finally, I modified these slightly to work properly on my implementation.

```
     evens [x] = [x];    evens (x:xs) = x:odds xs
     odds  [x] = [];      odds (_:xs) =  evens xs
```

How they work is `evens` does the work. It builds the output list. It takes the first item of a list fed it and makes it the first or next item of the output list. It calls `odds` with the remainder of the list. `odds` simply returns the tail of what it received back to `evens`.

Like tail, it discards the first item of what it receives.

`evens` produces a list with about half of the items discarded. `odds` produces nothing but does the critical discarding.

If you give `evens` the list [0,1,2,3,4] it returns every other item starting with 0, that is, [0,2,4]. If you give evens the list [1,2,3,4] it returns [1,3] because the list started with and odd number. Wherever `evens` starts, that's what it produces.

Try either with [1,1,1,1,1] or "bcdefg"

The modifications made to the functions reflect what each does respectively with the remaining element. odds discards it, evens attaches it to the end of the output list.

Both functions only work properly if given a list starting with an even number. If given a list with an odd number they work in reverse.

Here is a function that will produce an even or odd list depending on a specified starting number and ending in the specified ending number.

```
eo s e = [s,s+2..e]
```