# simultaneous recurrence relations in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to set up a system of simultaneous recurrence relations in haskell? I'm trying to implement

```
a(n)=3a(n-1)+2b(n-1)

b(n) = a(n-1) + 2b(n-1)
```

Input:

```
 a n = 3 * a (n-1) + 2 * b (n-1)
```

Output:

```
<interactive>:103:25: error: Variable not in scope: b :: t -> a
```

So, neither can I define a without defining b first, but nor can I define b without defining a first. I'm not sure if doing so is possible?

PS: I'm working in gchi

Comment: The term you're looking for is [mutual recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431125/mutual-recursion-in-odd-even-functions-in-haskell) which is possible in [tag:haskell].  If you're using GHCi, it might help for you to turn on the multiline mode with `:set +m` and define both at the same time using `let`

Comment: Also note that such definitions will lead to an exponential-complexity algorithm. Don't expect it to reasonably work for large input values.

Comment: @chi but doesn't the compiler handle that for us automatically?

Comment: The compiler will not turn an inefficient algorithm into an efficient one. If you need an efficient algorithm, you need to provide it to the compiler.

Comment: @chi I don't know if you are expert on Haskell. But Haskell is a purely functional language, meaning that in Haskell you have to define functions recursively, there are no for loops. However, I heard that haskell compiler is intelligent and will determine how to compile efficiently and functions don't call each other in the order you thought.

Comment: The compiler is not that magic. Anyway, I'm not saying you should trust me -- write your program using that direct recursive approach and observe the time. GHC implements recursion efficiently, but an exponential-time algorithm will still be exponential, only with a lower constant factor. (And I'm not suggesting to avoid recursion completely, which is both impossible and pointless in Haskell, but to research for new equivalent algorithms, if possible, or trying to use, say, memoization or some other technique to improve the complexity.)

Comment: @chi I mean the compiler should find the optimum machine codes by turning recursion into for loops, in other words, converting an exponential time algorithm into polynomial time algorithms. If the compiler is not that magic then someone will try to fix in the future. Artificial intelligence may be applied here to make the compiler more intelligent.

Comment: @chi The compiler is already magic if you didn't know. In Haskell, the source code written for humans to read is exponential, but the executable machine code is polynomial. The compiler handles all that performance optimization for you. The reason for the preference to recursion is that it improves readability by making the code neater and more concise. For performance issues, we still have to use for loops when it compiles to machine codes, (readability is not a concern here since machine codes aren't meant to be read by humans), so the machine codes are polynomial, not exponential.

Comment: I wish I had a compiler so smart to turn any EXPTIME algorithm into a PTIME algorithm when possible. With that, we could solve the P vs NP problem by just compiling an EXPTIME SAT solver! Truth is, there no such a compiler available. GHC is very nice, and includes many optimizations, but it is not magic. I strongly recommend you try computing the 1000000th Fibonacci number using the inefficient recursive algorithm and the manually memoized one. GHC won't turn the first in the second one.

Comment: Further, finding the "optimum machine codes" would violate well-known Computability results -- with that we could solve many problems which we know to be unsolvable algorithmically. This is an immediate consequence of Rice's theorem.

Comment: @chi of course it will never turn every exp algorithm into a ptime algorithm, only in limited cases. Maybe in the future some strong AI will be able to memoize on its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Haskell the order of definitions doesn't matter. You can define `a` before `b` or `b` before `a`, and in both cases they can reference each other just fine:

```
a n = 3 * a (n-1) + 2 * b (n-1)
b n = a (n-1) + 2 * b (n-1)
```

If you're working in GHCi (please clarify that), then yes, it won't accept a definition of `a` alone, because it doesn't know what `b` is. You can, however, give GHCi both definitions together, by enclosing them in `:{ ... :}`, like so:

```
*Prelude> :{                             
*Prelude| a n = 3 * a (n-1) + 2 * b (n-1)
*Prelude| b n = a (n-1) + 2 * b (n-1)    
*Prelude| :}
```

Finally, I have to note that these definitions, as written, will produce an infinite loop: there are no cases (i.e. no inputs) for which `a` and `b` don't call themselves recursively. This means that, once you call any of them, they will just keep calling each other forever.

To fix that, you need to provide a base case - an input, or a set of inputs, where the functions don't call themselves, for example:

```
a 0 = 1
a n = 3 * a (n-1) + 2 * b (n-1)

b 0 = 1
b n = a (n-1) + 2 * b (n-1)
```

(I can't tell whether I provided the correct base cases, because I don't know what your original problem is, and so can't say what is "correct" in your context; the base cases I provided are just examples to illustrate how it might be done)