# Haskell recursive types int2nat

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am studying Programming in Haskell by Hutton.

Below is the code on page 102.

```
int2nat :: Int -> Nat
int2nat 0 = Zero
int2nat (n+1) = Succ (int2nat n)
```

I am getting a parse error in pattern: n + 1.
It seems like Int does not accept n+1 as integer because of n.
How do I fix this issue?

I've also tried changing:

```
  data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

to `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving Show`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a "n + k patterns" wich is not supported in Haskell.

You should change your code in this way:

```
int2nat :: Int -> Nat
int2nat 0 = Zero
int2nat n = Succ (int2nat (n-1))
```

How is written in the comments read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010) for more.

Moreover if you insert a negative number it won't terminates.
To avoid this problem maybe you can try this:

```
int2nat :: Int -> Nat
int2nat 0 = Zero
int2nat n | n < 0  = Zero
          | otherwise = Succ (int2nat (n-1))
```