# Set up Haskell Project and run tests

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to set up a Haskell project (library) with tests that I can use to work through [The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths, and Programming](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/HR/). There are three parts that I'd like to have:

- The code that comes with the book, in a subdirectory
- The code I write for exercises in the book; one file per chapter
- The code I write for tests; one file per chapter

I have attempted a project setup [here](https://github.com/shterrett/haskell-road/tree/configure-tests), but am getting the following cabal error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring haskell-road-0.1.0.0...
Building haskell-road-0.1.0.0...
Failed to install haskell-road-0.1.0.0
Build log ( /Users/stuart/.cabal/logs/haskell-road-0.1.0.0.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '.'
Configuring haskell-road-0.1.0.0...
Building haskell-road-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing library haskell-road-0.1.0.0...

src/Chapter1.hs:1:1:
    File name does not match module name:
    Saw: ‘Main’
    Expected: ‘Chapter1’
cabal: Leaving directory '.'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haskell-road-0.1.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I'd like to be able to run `$ cabal test` and have all of the tests run, and have the import paths work. Any help is appreciated. I think there are probably issues with the test structure, but I've had trouble finding definitive guides on the actual setup.

EDIT: More details

```
src/
  Chapter1.hs
  Book/
    GS.hs
    etc....
test/
  Chapter1Test.hs
  MainTestSuite.hs
  TestHelper.hs
```

haskell-book.hs:

```
-- Initial haskell-road.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

-- The name of the package.
name:                haskell-road

-- The package version.  See the Haskell package versioning policy (PVP)
-- for standards guiding when and how versions should be incremented.
-- https://wiki.haskell.org/Package_versioning_policy
-- PVP summary:      +-+------- breaking API changes
--                   | | +----- non-breaking API additions
--                   | | | +--- code changes with no API change
version:             0.1.0.0

-- A short (one-line) description of the package.
-- synopsis:

-- A longer description of the package.
-- description:

-- The license under which the package is released.
license:             MIT

-- The file containing the license text.
license-file:        LICENSE

-- The package author(s).
author:              Stuart Terrett

-- An email address to which users can send suggestions, bug reports, and
-- patches.
maintainer:          shterrett@gmail.com

-- A copyright notice.
-- copyright:

-- category:

build-type:          Simple

-- Extra files to be distributed with the package, such as examples or a
-- README.
extra-source-files:  ChangeLog.md

-- Constraint on the version of Cabal needed to build this package.
cabal-version:       >=1.10


library
  -- Modules exported by the library.
  exposed-modules:     Chapter1, Book.COR, Book.DB, Book.FAIS, Book.FCT, Book.GS, Book.Hierarchy, Book.IAR, Book.Nats, Book.POL, Book.Polynomials, Book.PowerSeries, Book.Query, Book.REL, Book.SetEq, Book.SetOrd, Book.STAL, Book.TAMO, Book.TUOLP, Book.WWN

  -- Modules included in this library but not exported.
  -- other-modules:

  -- LANGUAGE extensions used by modules in this package.
  other-extensions:    FlexibleInstances

  -- Other library packages from which modules are imported.
  build-depends:       base, random >=1.1 && <1.2, HUnit >=1.3 && <1.4

  -- Directories containing source files.
  hs-source-dirs:      src

  -- Base language which the package is written in.
  default-language:    Haskell2010


test-suite haskell-road-tests
  type:              exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:    tests, src
  main-is:           MainTestSuite.hs
  build-depends:     base,
                     HUnit,
                     QuickCheck,
                     test-framework,
                     test-framework-hunit,
                     test-framework-quickcheck2
```

MainTestSuite.hs

```
import Chapter1Test

exitProperly :: IO Counts -> IO ()
exitProperly m = do
  counts <- m
  exitWith $ if failures counts /= 0 || errors counts /= 0 then ExitFailure 1 else ExitSuccess

allTests::[Test]
allTests = [Chapter1Test.itRuns]

main :: IO ()
main = exitProperly (runTestTT (TestList allTests))
```

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question itself. The github link is not guaranteed to still work in the future.

Comment: @hugomg extra information added

Comment: Added a diff of all changes to my answer.

Comment: Have you considering using Stack as your build system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diff of all changes:

http://lpaste.net/5997592404872396800

Specific changes you need to make:

1. In Chapter1.hs make sure `module Chapter1` appears before the import statement:

   ```
   module Chapter1 where
   import ...
   ```
2. In each of the Book modules you need to add the prefix `Book.` to
   each of the module statements, e.g. in `Book/COR.hs`:

   ```
   change:  module COR
       to:  module Book.COR
   ```

   Also, any import statement will also need the `Book.` prefix, i.e. in `Book/STAL.hs`:

   ```
   change:  import DB
       to:  import Book.DB
   ```

   (It might easier just to leave the book's modules at the top-level of the module name space.)
3. To fix this compilation error:

   ```
   src/Book/IAR.hs:131:7:
       No instance for (Foldable t3) arising from a use of ‘foldr’
   ```

just add `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to the top of `Book/IAR.hs` (it should be the very first line.)

4. To fix this compilation error:

   ```
   src/Book/FAIS.hs:14:4: Parse error in pattern: n + 1
   ```

   change: `f (n+1) = True : f n` to `f n = True : f (n-1)`.

   This is called an `n+k pattern` and more info about it (and why it has been deprecated) is available here: [What are "n+k patterns" and why are they banned from Haskell 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010)
5. In the `test-suite` section you have:

   ```
   hs-source-dirs: tests, src
   ```

   To use the code in the `src` directory you tests should depend on the `haskell-road` library instead of compiling the source code. That is, use these lines in the `test-suite` section:

   ```
   hs-source-dirs: tests
   build-depends: base, haskell-road, HUnit, ...
   ```
6. File `test/Chapter1Test.hs` needs a module statement:

   ```
   module Chapter1Test where
   ```

   and also fix this `import` statement:

   ```
   -import TestHelper.testCase
   +import TestHelper (testCase)
   ```
7. File `test/MainTestSuite.hs` needs these import statements:

   ```
   import System.Exit
   import Test.HUnit
   ```
8. File `test/testHelper.hs` needs to be renamed to `test/TestHelper.hs`
   and also needs this import statement:

   ```
   import Test.HUnit
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I also had to remove the `test-framework` lines in cabal, but it's building and testing now.

Answer (score 0):

[Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/) has 
[developing packages link](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-1.24.0.0/doc/users-guide/developing-packages.html) and cabal file content structure is described there.

By looking the error message, it seems that your haskell **library** source file Chapter1 starts with `module Main where`. It should contain `module Chapter1 where`, as the error message says.

Libraries should not contain `main` while the test-executables should, which is why you state in the cabal file the test executables with `main-is`.

Hope this helps! (I didn't look at the github sources, just the error message.)