# Python:Why i can't put in e.g. (x+1) inside def function(here)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, user-defined-functions

```
def function(x+4):
    return (x*5)+3
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why is that? i don't get the logic behind it?
(i know that it is a simple question but i couldn't find an answer to it.

i got many unclear feedbacks about my question,i am sorry about that as english is not my first language i couldn't clarify my question in short:

While i was learning about what return does,i compromised the logic with the logic behind f(x)= codomain as def function(x) = return codomain
but as you know there are functions in maths like f(x+2) = 5x+3. I thought maybe i could do the same on def function,the problem was it was giving a syntax error ,and i was curious about the design idea behind it and if there was an alternative solution to implement this in code.Thanks for answers!

Comment: You just cant, it's not part of Python syntax

Comment: it just makes no sense.

Comment: Why would you *want* to?

Comment: arguments must be placeholders.. just same as variables. can you have a variable names `x+4`?? ie can you do `x+4 = 3`?? then you call `x+4` to get 3?? its illogical. Even common sense does not allow for that. The moment you see `x+4=3` clearly you are supposed to solve for x..

Comment: Even if Python let you do that, why would you expect those 2 functions to be equivalent? If x=10, the 2nd one returns 73, but to be consistent the 1st one should return 33.

Comment: @Aran-Fey i don't. i just had to know why because otherwise it feels meaningless and while i am getting into deeper levels of knowledge i have to clear off my mind from minor curiousity.thanks for answering anyway :)

Comment: @PM2Ring i don't expect those to be equal because the first one would be function(14) = returned 53 and second one would be function(10)= returned 73 just like in mathematics :f(x) right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if you call the first one with a value of 10 it ought to interpret that as `x+4` equaling 10, so x=6, and so the function should return 6*5+3 = 33

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? By that somewhat argumentative-sounding question, I mean: do you think an arbitrary expression in `x` can be supplied? If so, given `def foo(x**2 - 1): return x`, what should the value of `foo(10)` be, 3 or -3? If not, what *is* allowed?

Comment: @chepner i could use abs(x) in every x if thats the case.
i was thinking it as it is in mathematics but as i was told it's just not part of python's syntax..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather uncommon syntax you are suggesting and it is simply not part of Python's syntax, or any language that I know.

Although, what you want to do boils down to updating an argument before it is passed to a function. This can be done with a *decorator*.

```
def add_four_to_argument(f):
    return lambda x: f(x + 4)


@add_four_to_argument
def func(x):
    return (x*5)+3

print(func(1)) # 28
```

Comment: Haskell had something [vaguely similar, but removed them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010).

Comment: You can also use currying with this. If you really want to make it more flexible you can also create a function that returns the decorator with the value you passed to that function. Like this: `add = lambda b: lambda f: lambda x: f(x + b)`. This is the currying `add(4)(func)(1) # 28`, but also still as decorator: `@add(4); func(x):...`

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked about the logic behind that design decision, how would you expect that syntax to behave? Note that it is not the same `x` being shared everywhere. The following are the same:

```
x = 5
def f(x):
    return x
print(f(x))  # Prints 5

x = 5
def f(y):
    return y
print(f(x))  # Prints 5
```

This allows you to **scope** your variables and not have to debug the confusing shared state that exclusive use of global variables can cause.

Back to your question though, **nowhere else in Python** does the *addition* operator cause *assignment* (barring abuse of dunder methods...don't do that). So, in your hypothetical `f(x+4)`, what happens to the `x+4`? Is that supposed to be a placeholder for `x=x+4`, or is that supposed to be assigned to some new variable representing some ethereal notion of "argument 1" for the function?

Let's dive into it a little further. What about the following example:

```
def f(x+y):
    return x
```

Suddenly things got a whole lot more ambiguous. How do we call this function? Do we use `f(1,2)`? Do we only pass a single argument `f(3)` and guess which portion corresponds to `x` and which corresponds to `y`? Even if we figure out the semantics for calling such a function, what does the statement `x+y` actually do? Does it stand for `x=x+y`? For `y=x+y`? For `arg1=x+y`?

By not allowing the behavior you're describing, Python makes your **intent clear**. To do a thing, you have to tell Python to actually do that thing. From the Zen of Python,

> explicit is better than implicit.