# pattern matching of negative literals in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I was trying to understand why n + k patterns were banned in Haskell. A famous post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010) gives an example of a function as follows:

```
f 0 = 0
f (n + 5) = 5
```

Haskell shows an error while matching f 1, f 2, f 3, f 4.
I cannot understand why (-1) cannot be matched with n. Firstly, I thought that integers only contain non-negative literals (0,1,..), but Haskell's definition of [Int](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Int) type includes negative literals.

Comment: That's simply how it was. And exactly a reason why the behaviour was considered "surprising".

Comment: Likely, it's because the underlying theory for n+k patterns is based on natural numbers. The fact that the implementation *could* be extended to `Num` instances is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't -1 be matched? That's simply how n+k patterns were defined, presumably because it seemed like a good idea at the time. It's natural to use induction for natural numbers, so why not define our cool n+k patterns to work for naturals? From [the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.17.2):

> Matching an n+k pattern (where n is a variable and k is a positive integer literal) against a value v succeeds if x >= k, resulting in the binding of n to x - k, and fails otherwise. Again, the functions >= and - are overloaded, depending on the type of the pattern. The match diverges if the comparison diverges.

The fact that you found this surprising is probably one reason why n+k patterns were removed. Another is that there's no need for them: you can easily translate any n+k pattern into a pattern not using this feature.

Comment: What was it banned? they could have changed the definition to include negative integers.   Did that kind of pattern matching break anything in Haskell?

Comment: @CaelanMiron As a professional Haskeller, nothing has been a bigger maintenance nightmare than the few times they *changed* the meaning of a language extension rather than simply eliminating it and introducing a new one. If you're talking about the base language, where you can't even opt out of the change, it seems likely to be even worse.

Comment: “there's no need for them: you can easily translate any n+k pattern into a pattern not using this feature” – well, much the same argument could be made for all syntactic extensions. IMO it would still be nice to have a better version of n+k patterns, but I also agree that the problems with the original ones were enough to warrant getting rid of them entirely.

Comment: That sentence seems to mix up `x` with `v`. Or something. Looks like a Report bug.

Comment: @CaelanMiron Changing the match semantics is a bad idea. Consider `f (n + 4) = g n ; f n = h n`. With the original semantics, `f 3` is `h 3`, with yours (removing the comparison) becomes `g (-1)`. About the ban: it was the only pattern mentioning a non-constructor function (`+`), and only working in one of many possible cases: `1+n+2` was not allowed, `2*n+1` was not allowed. Today we also have view patterns and pattern synonyms that extend patterns in a *general* way, and IMO there is no longer any need for such specific patterns.