# Factorial Creation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, factorial

I was recently [reading a paper](https://watermark.silverchair.com/nwv042.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAA0kwggNFBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggM2MIIDMgIBADCCAysGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMnndhS-4bs28YSW6FAgEQgIIC_Id1VQLwZd7lR_eFFEJV3Rb2tuH_GApXUvf25z1UNm-uqkidsRUGIZlTpEi2UnInVKoImoXJ49AaqRQAhXDlkoSa60eaQrQynBELlivZvRdh2pHm7OmxRLvGUDrqWgRuHApWeygukCuQHZ4hthpHhpy_2l_oggC4SnASSej_j19d7HH1datnxkSwMPt21e69wJ8-tCJH1fLpwprj1tXj_wG2nbr6MGhoimJG1nAh_JAB4qNgdmVDrRfhw5ZWSevXvX3rGVbH3JdZoBP7gmr-QQCl0DJl6vvAKCbNLtXwafKBPnvIxVwYn0SHskhASLb82uKNdhQuh-2J5eqJZv10NFthrS_fzgsuEDQ-77NWSXxq8IVJemNtUYLUU06k5YxfZWSJCeQ6ZlcgFkpFOWE3wWKEZFoRg05BG87n1wPMOXvzaMqf-mIrFkvAp-iJfkVzeX87JUtQpfVJM4yI0CtW1oL7MfjmDmGhy1gloa5W8U1l35b4HfnRq5g_u3zHnUH3VnMcGXEMWnbW9cD2whNwlaTiaBf_REN03e_Hl4_fzM6Gp4DwKT1crHKQuRB9fMM-3fjsL2fM29EsLDDwY6QnFLmRtMqnr4_s_CCzxqFoamClA4hHiHjDMW-dOBLfRbWdo4D_6YG5NnJAKGoKGJlWurWQFseqJ9KfatWaMx1z3xaVYlTBdQJxxbTRxvCLK02aVpMoVxXYw7ri3yypWm2NzfQMANtXoU9K7odoGqAHvdu8JPhXL8LXvJx1XvCOtUi7ZsaKM9k7-GE2g6OuYK8AMToIFgb77X5vAimQlz4M580Ea89LyA4a5Ab0YQIzHYlQlf84-6Bb2puMPtdZ_NjA5zoTKblxWDJB8U1bhVZCIsNRkuoSVx6uNE4GwUP6IS3NFP8mzY3Vwaa7RyvQz-1WdzzMrgtaksABFBvM_e6xLmTkOUk045THmlkDg5zDUIaKxG9sKn7p0DyK5YVyYhAE8n3upaWLsJc_lTm1Ma2S9BkmU-4kDcM53Fyztbml) where the defintion for a factorial is given as such:

```
fac 0 = 1
fac (n + 1) = (n + 1) ∗ fac n
```

I implemented the program from the paper as below:

```
fac :: Integer -> Integer
fac 0 = 1
fac (n + 1) = (n + 1) ∗ fac n
```

I then tried to use `Num a` as an alternative, thinking the type signature might be the problem.

```
fac :: Num a => a -> a
fac 0 = 1
fac (n + 1) = (n + 1) ∗ fac n
```

But when I try to compile this using GHCi, for both of the problems I get the following error:

```
Factorial.hs:5:6: error: Parse error in pattern: n + 1
  |
5 | fac (n + 1) = (n + 1) ∗ fac n
```

Can anyone explain why the error occurs?

*Thanks*

I've tried implementing the code in the paper as shown. I also added the type signature not in the paper. I then tried a less constraining type in the type signature. All with the same error.

Comment: By default, `n+1` is not a proper Haskell pattern. In the past, Haskell did have such "n+k" patterns, and your document has probably been written when n+k patterns were supported. You might want to try your luck defining (fac n) as something involving (n-1). See [SO-q3748592](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010).

Comment: The link you shared does not work. Did you mean this paper: https://doi.org/10.1093/nsr/nwv042

Comment: Corrective: you can still (as of v8.8) have n+k patterns, provided you switch the NPlusKPatterns extension on. But this is not encouraged for new code.

Comment: The NPlusKPatterns were a bit of a misfeature if I recall correctly, yes, it is nice synax, but that is probably the only advantage to it.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem the problem is not that it's "only nice syntax", you could also say that about monadic `do` notation. The problem is that n+k-patterns had confusing and error-prone semantics and were pretty much only reliably useful for the Peano-deconstruction scenario as in this question. Perhaps we should have an `NPlus1Patterns` extension that only supports this specific case...

Answer (score 7):

By default, `n+1` is *currently* not a proper Haskell pattern. In the past, Haskell did have such "n+k" patterns, and your document has probably been written when n+k patterns were supported.

The feature can still be used with recent compilers, provided the `NPlusKPatterns` language extension is explicitly switched on. For example, the following code works as expected:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  NPlusKPatterns  #-}

fac :: Integral a => a -> a
fac 0 = 1
fac (n + 1) = (n + 1) * (fac n)


main :: IO()
main = do
   putStrLn $ "Factorial of 7 is: " ++ (show $ fac 7)
```

A significant part of the Haskell community had come to regard n+k patterns as a misfeature, hence their removal from the language when the Haskell 2010 standard came out.

So the proper modern syntax is just:

```
fac :: Integral a => a -> a
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * (fac (n-1))
```

Related SO question: see [what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748592/what-are-nk-patterns-and-why-are-they-banned-from-haskell-2010)